# The number 0.6 is not converting to a fraction correctly

Tags: python, fractions

I am trying to create a program that factors quadratics. I was mostly successful, but I am having trouble with the quadratic `5x^2 -13x + 6` in which one of the roots is 0.6, or 3/5. I want to write it as a fraction, but it is not working correctly. It is giving me the following:

`5(x - 2)(x - 5404319552844595/9007199254740992)`

This is the code I used after importing from fractions:

```
    s1 = Fraction(((-b + sqrt(disc))/(2*a)))
    s2 = Fraction(((-b - sqrt(disc))/(2*a)))
```

Anyone know why this may not be working correctly? Or an easier way to factor the quadratics would be useful too.

Comment: [I'll just leave this here...](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html)

Comment: I'm kind of new to this and that is really confusing. I saw a polynomial division function, but not factoring. I didn't quite understand the roots one. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [Python manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html):

> Note that due to the usual issues with binary floating-point (see
>   [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues)), the argument to
>   Fraction(1.1) is not exactly equal to 11/10, and so Fraction(1.1) does
>   not return Fraction(11, 10) as one might expect.

The suggested treatment for a case when you know the numerator and denominator must be small is to [limit the denominator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator). Here is an example:

```
from math import sqrt
from fractions import Fraction
a, b, c = 5, -13, 6
disc = b * b - 4 * a * c
s1 = Fraction(((-b + sqrt(disc))/(2*a)))
s2 = Fraction(((-b - sqrt(disc))/(2*a)))
print (s1, s2)
s1, s2 = s1.limit_denominator (), s2.limit_denominator ()
print (s1, s2)
```

The first one prints the fraction you mentioned, the second one gives 3/5.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(0.6)
Fraction(5404319552844595, 9007199254740992)
>>> Fraction("0.6")
Fraction(3, 5)
```

`0.6` can't be represented exactly as a binary `float`. See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). This is not a Python issue, it's an issue with how floating point numbers work.